# react-native-react-bridge won't pass message using emit

Tags: react-native, webassembly

Alright, I've been breaking my head trying to get this to work.

I'm competant enough in react-native to get Expo working! I'm fairly still new though.

I want to use some WebAssembly components in react-native.

I chose to use the npm package: [react-native-react-bridge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-react-bridge)

So, far it seems as though I've followed the instructions correctly.
I made my wasm module as a separate *.tsx file with the following contents:

**HashBridge.tsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { webViewRender, useNativeMessage, emit } from 'react-native-react-bridge/lib/web';

const Blake3 = () => {
    const [messageData, setMessageData] = useState(null);
    console.log('Entering WASM');
    // useNativeMessage hook receives message from React Native
    useNativeMessage((message) => {
        if (message.type === 'makeHmac') {
            setMessageData(message.data);
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (messageData) {
            const { hmac_msg, derivedKey } = messageData;
            // Perform your hashing operation here
            const token = 'your_generated_token';
            emit({ type: 'tokenGenerated', data: token });
        }
    }, [messageData]);

    return null;
};

export default webViewRender(<Blake3 />);
```

Then I am rendering it in my splashscreen file.

**SplashScreen.tsx**

```
import { get_user_id, getHmacReq, createWsClientWithToken } from '../crypto';
import WebView from "react-native-webview";
import { useWebViewMessage } from "react-native-react-bridge";
import webApp from "../HashBridge";

const SplashScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [hmac_msg, setHmacMsg] = useState(null);
    const [derivedKey, setDerivedKey] = useState(null);
    const [showWebView, setShowWebView] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const user_id = await get_user_id();
            const { hmac_msg, derivedKey } = await getHmacReq(user_id);
            setHmacMsg(hmac_msg);
            setDerivedKey(derivedKey);
            setShowWebView(false); // Hide the WebView after the data is fetched
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const { ref, onMessage, emit } = useWebViewMessage((message) => {
        console.log('Check');
        if (message.type === 'tokenGenerated') {
            console.log('Token generated: ', message.data);
            setShowWebView(true); // Show the WebView after the token is generated
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(1, hmac_msg, derivedKey);
        if (hmac_msg && derivedKey) {
            console.log(2, hmac_msg, derivedKey);
            emit({ type: 'makeHmac', data: { hmac_msg, derivedKey } });
            console.log(3, hmac_msg, derivedKey);
        }
    }, [hmac_msg, derivedKey]);

    return (
        <>
            <ImageBackground
                source={require('../assets/splash2.jpg')}
                resizeMode="cover"
                style={stylesInternal.bgImage}
            >
                {showWebView && (
                    <WebView
                        ref={ref}
                        source={{ html: webApp }}
                        onMessage={onMessage}
                        style={{ height: 0, width: 0 }} // Hide the WebView
                    />
                )}
                <Pressable
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('login')}
                    style={{ top: 350, right: 20, backgroundColor: "transparent", flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row-reverse' }}
                ><FadeInView style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row-reverse' }}>
                        <GradientText />
                        <Ionicons name="chevron-forward-outline" size={32} color={"white"} style={{ top: 362, right: 260 }} />
                    </FadeInView>
                </Pressable>
            </ImageBackground>
        </>
    )
};
```

The lines:

```
if (hmac_msg && derivedKey) {
    emit({ type: 'makeHmac', data: { hmac_msg, derivedKey } });
}
```

Definitely executed, since, I get the correct output from `console.log`. But, the emit doesn't seem to reach my wasm area. I.E. `const Blake3 = () => {`

I don't know if I've defined everything appropriately and could use some help.